# itext7 HTML to PDF table too long to lose data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf, itext7

i generated a table:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <title>Quotation preview</title>
  <link href="http://localhost:8080/api/styles/common.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://localhost:8080/api/styles/quotation.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    @page {
      margin-top: pt;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <table class="column">
    <tr class="font-small">
        <th class="text-align-left">Item</th>
        <th class="text-align-left">Product Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Period Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-align-center">1</td>
      <td class="p-no-margin">
          <strong>Akamai - Dynamic Site Accelerator</strong>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">Akamai Base Pricing (Platform fee) - Regular Site - per months package</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">- Include total: 2.2TB/per months share with MGTO websites</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">www.macaotourism.gov.mo &amp; 15 foreign language website</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">industry.macaotourism.gov.mo</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">fireworks.macaotourism.gov.mo</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">mtt.macaotourism.gov.mo</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">whatson.macaotourism.gov.mo</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">- Luna Control Center – provide usage reports and configuration</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">- Site Failover</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">- 5GB NetStorage</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">- Akamai Content Delivery Network - Service Level Agreement: 99.99%</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">- The service allows user to make configuration change request using</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">technical support hotline during normal office hours (Mon-Fri 9:00am</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">– 6:00pm). All the change request will be done by Akamai and log with</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">a support ticket number.</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">Period: Service from 1-Jan-2022 to 31-Dec-2022</p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">Remark: each month must commit 1.2TB</p>
          
          <p>
              <span>Domain: </span>
              <span>macaotourism.gov.mo</span>
          </p>
          <p>
              <span>Contract Period: </span>
              <span>2022-01-01</span>
              ---
            <span>2022-12-31</span>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="text-align-center nowrap">1 License(s)</td>
        <td class="text-align-center nowrap">12 MONTH</td>
      <td class="text-align-right">MOP69,975</td>
      <td class="text-align-right">MOP839,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-align-center">2</td>
      <td class="p-no-margin">
          <strong>Akamai - Image Manager</strong>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">Akamai Image Manager Per 10 mils hit per month </p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">Period: Service from 1-Jan-2022 to 31-Dec-2022</p>
          
          <p>
              <span>Domain: </span>
              <span>macaotourism.gov.mo</span>
          </p>
          <p>
              <span>Contract Period: </span>
              <span>2022-01-01</span>
              ---
            <span>2022-12-31</span>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="text-align-center nowrap">1 License(s)</td>
        <td class="text-align-center nowrap">12 MONTH</td>
      <td class="text-align-right">MOP6,700</td>
      <td class="text-align-right">MOP80,400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-align-center">3</td>
      <td class="p-no-margin">
          <strong>Akamai -  SSL Network Access-DV-SAN</strong>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">SSL network access : SAN certificate (Total: 12 Months) </p>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">Period: Service from 1-Jan-2021 to 32-Dec-2022</p>
          
          <p>
              <span>Domain: </span>
              <span>macaotourism.gov.mo</span>
          </p>
          <p>
              <span>Contract Period: </span>
              <span>2022-01-01</span>
              ---
            <span>2022-12-31</span>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="text-align-center nowrap">1 License(s)</td>
        <td class="text-align-center nowrap">12 MONTH</td>
      <td class="text-align-right">MOP8,625</td>
      <td class="text-align-right">MOP103,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-align-center">4</td>
      <td class="p-no-margin">
          <strong>Akamai - Dynamic Site Accelerator</strong>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">Additional:  1TB/per months share with MGTO websites</p>
          
          <p>
              <span>Domain: </span>
              <span>macaotourism.gov.mo</span>
          </p>
          <p>
              <span>Contract Period: </span>
              <span>2022-01-01</span>
              ---
            <span>2022-12-31</span>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="text-align-center nowrap">1000 License(s)</td>
        <td class="text-align-center nowrap">12 MONTH</td>
      <td class="text-align-right">0</td>
      <td class="text-align-right">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-align-center">5</td>
      <td class="p-no-margin">
          <strong>Akamai - Dynamic Site Accelerator</strong>
          
              <p class="product-description-wrap">Base usage : 1.2TB/per months share with MGTO websites</p>
          
          <p>
              <span>Domain: </span>
              <span>macaotourism.gov.mo</span>
          </p>
          <p>
              <span>Contract Period: </span>
              <span>2022-01-01</span>
              ---
            <span>2022-12-31</span>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="text-align-center nowrap">1200 License(s)</td>
        <td class="text-align-center nowrap">12 MONTH</td>
      <td class="text-align-right">0</td>
      <td class="text-align-right">0</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

then i use springTemplateEngine, HtmlConverter cover this HTML to PDF with parameter

```
     private fun generatePDF(
        outputStream: OutputStream,
    ) {  
        val pdfDocument = PdfDocument(PdfWriter(outputStream))
       
        logger.info { "Generating PDF body html" }
        val bodyHtml = "" // replace with the HTML above

        //convert html to pdf
        logger.info { "Converting body html to PDF document" }
        val document = HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(bodyHtml, pdfDocument, converterProperties)

        //modify pdf to add footer
        logger.info { "Adding footer to PDF document" }
        val footer = Paragraph().apply {
            add(Text("123"))
        }
        (1..pdfDocument.numberOfPages).forEach { pageNumber ->
            val rectangle = pdfDocument.getPage(pageNumber).pageSize
            val x = rectangle.width / 2
            val y = rectangle.bottom + 20
            document.showTextAligned(
                footer,
                x,
                y,
                pageNumber,
                TextAlignment.CENTER,
                VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM,
                0f
            )
        }
        //close document to save
        logger.info { "Flushing PDF document to stream" }
        document.close()
    }
```

here is my local test controller and `generatePDFAsByteArray` function

```
    @GetMapping("preview/PDF/localTest")
    fun previewPDFLocalTest(@PathVariable quotationNumber: String) { 
        pdfService.generatePDFAsByteArray {
            pdfService.generatePDF(it)
        }.let {
            File("./quotation.pdf").writeBytes(it)
        }
    }
```

```
 fun generatePDFAsByteArray(outputStreamConsumer: (OutputStream) -> Unit): ByteArray {
        val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        outputStreamConsumer(byteArrayOutputStream)
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
    }
```

but finally got this PDF：
https://github.com/funnyJack/test/blob/main/quotation.pdf

i have 5 items, but this PDF only print 3 item, ITEXT cannot make the table paging?
can somebody help with this?

Comment: Hi, right now you are attaching the template only and it's not possible to reproduce your problem. Please try to minimize your code sample: only use minimal static HTML without any templates and show us the code that produces incorrect PDF from that HTML

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This themleaf template works fine, In my debugging process, it can generate full table HTML String  as variable `bodyHtml`. the problem is ITEXT can neither print this form on one page, nor can this table be divided into two pages to print. Is there any way to divide table into two pages by using template?

Comment: Please attach minimal code and HTML sample reproducing the problem. Minimal means there should be no Thymeleaf in it at all as it has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: See [mre] for more guidance.

Comment: Hi Alexey Subach , andrewJames , i'm sorry it's too busy to pay attention to this problem. I have changed my question，now i think it's a minimal, reproducible example. Can help with this issue please? Thank you very much !

Comment: Did you try adding a width percentage to the "Product Description" column. for an example add a css width 20% to class .p-no-margin

Comment: Not work, the table width is another problem, cause each row is incomplete, thanks for noticed that. but now the main issue is missing rows in PDF, any idea about that?